# Select a specific column with multiple includes in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to get specific columns from a context with several includes, but when I try:

```
Context.Include(i => i.c)
       .Include(i => i.l).Select(s=> new LocationCatalog { Name  = s.Name})
       .Include(i => i.p)
       .Include(i => i.li)
       .Include(i => i.pcl)
```

VS throws an error after the select.

How can I achieve this? I want to specify the columns for each include.

The error says that for example: i.p doesn't contains definition for i.l

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: You mentioned that an error is thrown. Could you please post also the error ? Thanks

Comment: The error says that for example: i.p doesn't contains definition for i.l

Comment: Please update your post with the error.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible with Entity Framework. You either include the entire table (with `Include`, as you are doing) or you don't include it at all.
If you want to load only specific columns, you can do this, but see how it's a manual process:

```
Context
    .Select(i => new YourType
    {
        c = i.l,
        l = i.l,
        x = new X 
        {
            a = i.x.a // only the properties you want here
        }
        ...
    });
```

The moment you use `Select`, `Include` is completely ignored, so you cannot use both.

Comment: Do you know what's faster tho?
Selecting the entire table with include and then apply filters or selecting only the needed column and then applying the filters. ecc...